# How to copy content from one tab to another in JavaFX?

Tags: tabs, javafx

I am trying to allow the user to create a new tab in my application.

I tried the `tab.setContent(tag.getContent());` but it moves the content of one tab to the other leaving the first one empty.

Is there a way to make a copy of the tab content ?

Comment: The only way I can do it is to use a copy constructor for the tab content.  Make a subclass of something like VBox and then make a constructor that takes (VBox)tabContent and copies it to the new instance.  I'd like to know if there's a better way!

Comment: I was playing with it. I think I found another way. I made a separate FXML file for the tabs only. And instantiated a new FXMLLoader and used it to create a new node root (loader.load();, which gives me an anchorpane as the root). Then created a new Tab object, and used the root to set the content of the tab object: mynewTab.setContent(tabroot).

Comment: That will work because it makes a new instance but it won't copy over any changed data.  Imagine a TextArea where the user entered something.  Whatever isn't set in the FXML file won't get created.

Comment: probably in this case, they will need to be wrapped in one object to pass variables values between the tabs I guess. no?

Comment: Yes.  What I'm talking about is a copy constructor (or doing clone() properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a separate FXML file for a tab, created a loader for the FXMl file, then load it to get the root. Use the root to build a scene and finally add the scene to the TabPane!