# How to duplicate a control on click

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, charts, javafx

I am trying to show a big chart when clicking on a small one.

This is my code:

```
final AreaChart<Number,Number> ac =  new AreaChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

    ac.adddata (......);   
    ac.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {

                   TabOane TabTab = new TabPane();
               Tab t = new Tab("Title");
               t.setContent(ac);
               TabTab.getTabs().clear();
               TabTab.getTabs().add(t);

             }
        });
```

But when it is clicked , the big chart is shown and the small one disappears. Is there a way of getting a copy of my chart in this case?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273820/how-to-copy-content-from-one-tab-to-another-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the creation of control (chart)  into a methode and call it from the   twice a time one from the event hendler (to creat the big chart ) and one to create the small one  .